# Diferença entre teste de aceitação e teste de sistema

Tags: terminologia, testes, engenharia-de-software

Na prática, qual a diferença entre o teste de aceitação e teste de sistema? E como fazê-los?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Teste de Validação

- O software está montado como um pacote e a validação do mesmo é realizada através de uma série de testes caixa preta
- finalidade:

  - demonstrar a conformidade aos requisitos funcionais e de desempenho
  - verificar se a documentação está correta
- duas possibilidades:

  - aceito
  - não está totalmente de acordo com os requisitos: negociar com o usuário
- engloba o Teste de Aceitação: realizado pelo próprio usuário
- no caso de software desenvolvido para vários usuários:

  - teste alfa: realizado pelo usuário no ambiente do desenvolvedor
  - teste beta: realizado pelo usuário em seu próprio ambiente

### Teste de Sistema

- considera o software dentro do seu ambiente mais amplo (todos os aspectos de interação com ele, como outro hardware, software, pessoas, etc.)
- corresponde a uma série de testes que tem por objetivo verificar se todos os elementos do sistema foram integrados adequadamente e realizam corretamente suas funções

  - **teste de segurança:** tem por objetivo verificar se todos os mecanismos de proteção protegem realmente o software de acessos indevidos.
  - **teste de estresse:** tem por objetivo confrontar os programas com situações anormais de freqüência, volume ou recursos em quantidade.
  - **teste de desempenho:** tem por objetivo testar o tempo de resposta do sistema e é aplicado, geralmente, para sistemas de tempo real

### Teste Unitário

- concentra-se no módulo
- utiliza a técnica de teste estrutural
- pode ser realizado em paralelo para vários módulos
- aspectos considerados
  Geralmente, um programa não é um módulo único, mas formado de diversos módulos que, para efeito do teste de unidade devem ser testados separadamente

### Teste de Integração

- constrói-se, de uma forma sistemática, a estrutura do programa realizando, ao mesmo tempo, testes para detectar erros de interface
- embora os módulos, depois do teste de unidade, funcionem corretamente de forma isolada, o teste de integração é necessário pois quando colocados juntos, várias situações inesperadas podem acontecer

<sup>Fonte: Resumo de aula de Engenharia de Software.</sup>

Como faze-los, vai depender de varias variáveis, como, tipo de tecnologia, ambiente de controle de projeto, equipe de homologação, capacitação técnica,  entre outros fatores.

Comment: Pesquisei um pouco mais sobre e achei alguns dados para ajudar a complementar: Teste de sistema testa os requisitos técnicos e a especificação do sistema. O de aceitação, por sua vez, assim como vc bem citou, valida o sistema de acordo com a necessidade do usuário final.

Comment: Trabalho em uma empresa que os processo são bem definidos, mas não posso passar os detalhes nem a ordem, mas faz diferença fazer os 2 além do *teste de integração*, que acho muito importante, se quiser posso complementar a resposta sobre o teste de integração...

Comment: Se não fosse abusar da sua boa vontade, seria interessante. Complementaria bastante o assunto.

Comment: Adicionei teste de integração e teste unitário ;)